# java overriding - field is not visible

Tags: java, overriding

I have a java public class I need to modify (only one method). The class is in a package so I'm writing a new class that extends the first class and overriding the method I need to change.

Class A is

```
public class A {
    GL gl;
    GLU glu;
    PGraphicsOpenGL pgrap;
    //other fields

    //constructor

    public void method() {
        this.gl = pgrap.gl;
        this.glu = pgrap.glu;
        //something else I don't want in class B
    }
}
```

Class B is something like

```
public class B extends A {

    //constructor that recalls super()

    public void method() {
        super.gl = pgrap.gl;
        super.glu = pgrap.glu;
    }
}
```

but I get an error for `super.gl = pgrap.gl`: `The field A.gl is not visible`. 
I don't have any getter method written in the package, what should I do?

Thanks.

NOTE: I am not able to recompile the package or add the class B to the package.

Comment: Define Class B in same package. Or change it to protected

Comment: use gatter and setter to access the variables or change the access level of variables to public.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default access specifier is `package-private` which means classes in the same package as `A` can access this variable using the instances of `A`

```
A a = ....
a.gl = ...; // this works.
```

And `package-private` members (and `private` members) are not inherited, only `protected` and `public` members are.

Since `A#method()` is already doing the assignment operation, you call `super.method()` in `B#method()` to get your desired behavior. Or you should mark them as `protected`.

Answer (score 3):

[Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

`A.gl` and `A.glu` are package-private (no explicit modifier).  The only way you'd be able to access them is if class B is in the same package as class A.

If they were protected you'd be able to access them as you wish:

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed
>   within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by
>   a subclass of its class in another package.

Answer (score 2):

Fields `gl` and `glu` have package access. Use `protected` access modifiers to make  accessible them in sub-classes.

Answer (score 1):

Define variables as `protected.`

```
protected int gl;
protected int glu;
```

Because your variables have default access you will be able to access them in the Same package. So you need to move either B or define them as `protected` so that they will be accessible to child classes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can't declare your class `B` in the same package of class `A` and you can't directly modifiy class `A` then only choice is to go by reflection:

```
public void method() {
  Field[] fields = this.getClass().getSuperClass().getDeclaredFields();

  for (Field field : fields) {
    if (field.getName().equals("gl")) {
      field.setAccessible(true);
      field.set(this, pgrap.gl);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I need cause your assumptions are right, but now I get `The function getSuperClass() does not exist` (I'm doing this in Processing btw)

Comment: Because I forgot to add getClass(), in any case I figured it was processing (it used it many times). The syntax provided by Processing, as a subset of Java, maybe enough, otherwise you will have to move to a real Java project (it's quite easy to embed a processing frame inside a normal Java applcation).

Comment: Still getting the same error... maybe cause it's Processing 1.2? Thanks for helping anyway, I'll try to use Processing for as long as I can, if I can't solve this I'll switch to Java